# Authenticating Samba Active Directory host with itself

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, domain-controller, samba4

So Ive been experimenting for quite some time now with running my Active Directory infrastructure on Samba based Domain Controllers.

And the for the most part it's been great!  However one small problem that I've run into. That no one seems to have documented or noted anywhere I've searched.

But how do I get the host machine running Samba to authenticate to itself using Samba?  So its much like on Windows Domain Controllers where they log into themselves using Domain Credentials?